# use the API to add a network to an external provider

Tags: python, ovirt

I'm using ovirtskd4 in python with oVirt Engine version 4.1.2.2-1.el7.centos.   I'm trying to create a new Network on an Openstack Network Provider.  If I use the web page GUI I can just click "Export" and select the provider from the pull down.

Similarly, if I use the api and do

```
conn.system_service().openstack_network_providers_service().list()
```

I see the `OpenStackNetworkProvider` instance I want.  I can't seem to find a path to either an `openstack_networks_service` that has an `add` method or a way to add an `external` or `provider` field to a `Network` object to create the external network.

What is the right way with the API to create a network using an external provider?

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't find a good solution for using the API directly for all of it, I did come up with a solution.  I first directly contact the Neutron server to create the network, then go back to the ovirt sdk to bring that network into the data center/cluster I want:

```
net_name = 'test_network'
data_center = 'Default'
net_dict = {'name': net_name} # add other parameters as desired
onps = conn.system_service().openstack_network_providers_service()
provider = onps.list()[0]

# get the URL of the provider, though in this case it might be "localhost" so swap that out for the host in the Connection url
url = "%s/v2.0/networks" % \
    (provider.url.replace('localhost', conn.url.split('/')[2]),)

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps({'network': net_dict}))

# now find that one
os_net_serv = onps.provider_service(provider.id).networks_service()
for os_net in os_net_serv.list():
    if os_net.name == net_name:
        net_serv = os_net_serv.network_service(os_net.id)
        net_serv.import_(data_center=ovirtsdk4.types.DataCenter(name=data_center))

# now I can get it as an oVirt Network
net = conn.system_service().networks_service().list(
    search='name=%s' % (net_name,))[0]
```